# struggling with Windows Forms grids

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

The DataGridView is not working the way I want.

I need it to create two colums:

```
using System.Data;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    DataTable todoList = new DataTable();
    bool isEditing = false;

    private void toDoListView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        /// Creating Colums
        todoList.Columns.Add("Title");
        todoList.Columns.Add("Description");

        ///Pushing out data souce to the data grid
        toDoListView.DataSource = todoList;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        titleOfTaskTextBox.Text = "";
        descriptionTextBox.Text = "";
    }

    private void editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isEditing = true;
        ///Need to fill text fields from data store
        titleOfTaskTextBox.Text = todoList.Rows[toDoListView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].ItemArray[0].ToString();
        descriptionTextBox.Text = todoList.Rows[toDoListView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].ItemArray[1].ToString();
    }

    private void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            todoList.Rows[toDoListView.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Delete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }

    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isEditing)
        {
            todoList.Rows[toDoListView.CurrentCell.RowIndex]["Title"] = titleOfTaskTextBox.Text;
            todoList.Rows[toDoListView.CurrentCell.RowIndex]["Description"] = descriptionTextBox.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            // -> This code is not accepted
            todoList.Rows.Add(titleOfTaskTextBox.Text, descriptionTextBox.Text);
        }
        /// Clear used fields
        titleOfTaskTextBox.Text = "";
        descriptionTextBox.Text = "";
        isEditing = false;
    }
}
```

It says that the marked line of code is wrong.

Comment: Did you take note of the reason why that line of code is not acceptable? Something about: *you cannot add rows to a bound Control*? -- You have the DataSource of the DataGridView set to a DataTable. Now the Control is bound to this source of data. Add rows to the source of data instead

Comment: its when i go to run it it says System.ArgumentException: 'Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.'

Comment: Sure. You have quite a number of mistakes here. The first is in the `CellContentClick` handler. You cannot do what you're doing there. Not even close. Search SO for questions related to the DataGridView Control or examples in the MSDN docs, in relation to binding a source of data to the grid

Comment: I've implemented a new method but its now syaing that the imput array is still too long for the coloums im very new to windows forms and its not very forgiving

Answer (score 0):

### Model - View

In modern programming there is a tendency to separate the data (= model) from how this data is displayed (= view).

This separation has the advantage, that the model can be reused in different views. For instance spreadsheetdata can be used to display in a table, but it can also be used to create a graph.

Apart from the possibility of reuse the  model, it has also the advantage that you can unit test the model without the program that displays the data. It is also possible to test the view using some mock data if the actual data is not available yet. Or maybe you want to change the way that the data is displayed, without changing the model.

To adapt the model to the view, an adapter class is needed, quite often called the `ViewModel`. Together these three classes are abbreviated as MVVM. If you are not familiar about MVVM, consider to spend an hour or so to read some background about this.

### Back to your question

You do too much in your form. If you had to write a specification for your form, you would say something that your form displays a `Todo list`, which is a list of `ToDo Items`. If the operator clicks on a button labeled `Remove`, the currently selected items in the displayed ToDoList are removed. If the operator clicks on button `Save`, then ... etc.

Did you notice that in your specification you didn't use the word DataTable? Sure, currently your Todo List is in a DataTable. But do you want to rewrite your form is your ToDoList would be in a database? or just a simple file? Or maybe the data is fetched from the internet?

By separating the model from the view, your code would be much easier to read, much easier to unit test, much easier to adapt for new uses, or to reuse.

So let's separate your code in model and View.

### Your Model

Apparently you have the notion of a collection of `ToDoItems`. You call this collection a `ToDoList`. How about this:

```
class ToDoItem
{
    public int Id {get; set;}         // not needed right now
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}

    // not sure if you need this, but keep in mind for future uses:
    public DateTime CreationDate {get; set;}
    public DateTime ExpectedFinishedDate {get; set;}
    public DateTime? ActualFinishedDate {get; set;}     // null as long as not finished

    public bool IsFinished => this.ActualFinishedData.HasValue;
}
```

I've added an Id to the ToDoItem, this might be handy if you want to identify the ToDoItem, for instance if in future use you want to add a list of people who have to  finish the TodoItem. If you think this is really nonsense, leave it out.

And your TodoList.

```
class ToDoList : ICollection<ToDoItem>
{
    private ICollection<ToDoItem> ToDoItems {get} new List<ToDoItem>();

    // implementation of the interface is straightforward:
    public int Count => this.ToDoItems.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => this.ToDoItems.IsReadOnly;

    public void Add(ToDoItem todoItem)
    {
         this.ToDoItems.Add(todoItem);
    }

    // etc
}
```

The nice thing, is that you've hidden that the ToDoList is actually a List in memory. If in a future version you want to save it in a database, or fetch the data from the internet, the users of your class won't have to notice this, and thus won't have to change.

Consider to have a constructor that takes an `ICollection<ToDoItem>` as parameter. You can also decide to create a class ToDoFile:

```
class ToDoFile
{
    public FileInfo File {get; set;}
    public ToDoList Read() {...}
    public void Write(IEnumerable<ToDoItem> todoItems) {...}
}
```

Note that I could have added `Save(string fileName)` to ToDoList. But are you sure that every ToDoList can be saved as a file? Could it be that some ToDoLists in future will be saved in a database? Do you want to Limit your ToDoList for this?

### The View

You didn't give a full specification of your form. It seems to me that you want to display your ToDoList in a DataGridView. You want buttons to Add / Remove ToDoItems, and if the operator clicks on one of the cells in the DataGridView, he can edit the contents of the Cell. When the operator has finished making all changes, he can click on the `Apply Now` button to activate the changes he made. A cancel button undoes the changes.

How about this:

```
class FormToDo : Form
{
    // your Form has a ToDoList; initialize this before the Form is shown
    public ToDoList ToDoList {get; set;}
```

Using the visual studio designer add the buttons that you need and the DataGridView that will show your ToDoItems. Add the DataGridViewColumns to show the properties that you want to show. No need to add columns for properties that you don't want to show.

Define in the constructor which column will show which property:

```
    public FormToDo()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent(); // added by visual studio designer

        // define which column shows which property:
        this.columnTitle.DataPropertyName = nameof(ToDoItem.Title);
        this.columnDescription.DataPropertyName = nameof(ToDoItem.Description);
        this.columnExpectedFinishedDate.DataPropertyName = nameof(ToDoItem.ExpectedFinishedDate);
        ... // etc
    }
```

Of cours your form needs a property to fetch the ToDoItems that must be shown initially:

```
public IEnumerable<ToDoItem> InitialToDoList => this.ToDoList;
```

If in future your requirement changes, for instance that the initial ToDoList is fetched from a file, or from the internet, then this is the only statement that changes.

To show this ToDoList, all you have to do is assign it to the DataGrigView.DataSource just before the form is shown:

```
public OnFormShown(object sender, ...)
{
    this.dgvToDoList.DataSource = this.InitialToDoList.ToList();
}
```

And presto, your form is shown! However, it is not easy to access the edited data. For this you need to put the references to your ToDoItems in a [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1?view=net-8.0).

```
private BindingList<ToDoItem> DisplayedToDoList
{
    get => (BindingList<ToDoItem>) this.dgvToDoList.DataSource;
    set => this.dgvToDoList.DataSource = value;
}

public OnFormShown(object sender, ...)
{
    this.DisplayedToDoList = new BindingList<ToDoItem>(this.InitialToDoList.ToList());
}
```

Now all your edits are easily accessible, even rows that are added to or removed from the displayed table.

If the operator has finished editing the table, he clicks the `Apply Now` button to activate the changes:

```
private void OnApplyNow_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    // fetching the edited data is a one liner:
    ICollection<ToDoItem> editedToDoList = this.DisplayedToDoList;

    // process the edited data (out of scope of this answer)
    this.ProcessEditedData(editedToDoList);
}
```

To process the edited data, consider to compare the edited data with the original ones, check the changes for validity and save the changes.

By the way, did you notice that all methods and properties contain only one or two statements?

The datagridview supports adding and removing rows. You wanted to add some extra buttons: one to Add a new ToDoItem, and one to Remove the currently selected ones.

You need properties to access the selected rows. Luckily they are also properties that contain only one line:

```
private ToDoItem CurrentToDoItem =>(ToDoItem) this.dgvToDoList.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;


private IEnumerable<ToDoItem> SelectedToDoItems  => this.dgvToDoList.SelectedRows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>();

    // from every Row get the DataBoundItem:
    .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem

    // every DataBoundItem is a ToDoItem
    .Cast<ToDoItem>();
```

Now that you've properties to access the selected rows, it is easy to delete all selected ToDoItems at once:

```
private RemoveSelectedToDoItems()
{
    ICollection<ToDoItem> selectedToDoItems = this.SelectedToDoItems.ToList();

    // only if needed: ask the operator if remove is ok:
    bool permissionToRemove = this.AskOperatorPermissionToRemove(selectedToDoItems);

    if (permissionToRemove)
    {
        this.RemoveToDoItems(selectedToDoItems);
    }
}

private void RemoveToDoItems(ICollection<ToDoItem> itemsToRemove)
{
    IList<ToDoItem> remainingToDoItems = this.DisplayedToDoList
        .Except(itemsToRemove)
        .ToList();

    this.DisplayedToDoList = new BindingList(remainingToDoItems);
}
```

Your button handler will be a one liner:

```
private void OnButtonApplyNow_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.RemoveToDoItems();
}
```

Just like I separated the model from the view, I also separate the data handling from the buttons that activate this data handling. If for instance you don't want a button to do this, but for instance a menu item you can reuse `RemoveToDoItems`.

### Add ToDoItem - this will solve the error in your code

```
private void OnButtonAddToDoItem_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    // create the ToDoItem that must be added:
    ToDoItem todoItemToAdd = this.CreateToDoItemToAdd();

    // check if this ToDoItem is not null and correct
    bool todoItemOk = this.CheckToDoItemCanBeAdded(todoItemToAdd);

    if (todoItemOk)
    {
        // adding will be a one liner:
        this.DisplayedToDoList.Add(todoItemToAdd);
    }
}
```

To create a new ToDoItem depends on how this must be filled. For instance using a new dialog box:

```
private ToDoItem CreateToDoItemToAdd()
{
    using (var dlg = new FormFillToDo();
    {
        // if needed fill some properties before showing
        dlg. ... = ...;

        // show the dialog box and interpret the result
        DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog(this);
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ToDoItem todoItemToAdd = dlg.FilledToDoItem;
            return todoItemToAdd;
        }
        else
            return null; // nothing to add
    }
}
```

The check if the ToDoItem is valid, depends on your requirements. Should every Id be unique? Should the ExpectedFinishedData in the future? etc. I leave this implementation up to you.

### Summary

By separating the model from the view, most view handling are methods that contain only one or two statements.

It is way easier to unit test your model, you don't need a form for it, and it can be done automatically.

If you decide to change your model, for instance your data is fetched from a database instead from a file, your View will hardly change.

If your requirements change, for instance in future every ToDoItem must be assigned to a `Person` using a property `PersonId`, changes in your View will be minimal.

If in future you want to change your View, for instance you want to display a graph that shows the already finished ToDoItems, you can reuse class ToDoList, you can even reust the properties about Displayed ToDoItems.